# How to make static window increase size on mouse hover

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, button, hover

I have a bunch of windows inside another window.
Child Windows are created in the `CreateBoard()` method of `MainWindow` class. `Create()` method of `MainWindow` and `GemWindow` is from the [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/managing-application-state-) `BaseWindow` abstract class and this is where the each class is registered with a call to `RegisterClass()`

```
template <class DERIVED_TYPE>
class BaseWindow
{
public:
    static LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        DERIVED_TYPE* pThis = NULL;

        if (uMsg == WM_NCCREATE)
        {
            CREATESTRUCT* pCreate = (CREATESTRUCT*)lParam;
            pThis = (DERIVED_TYPE*)pCreate->lpCreateParams;
            SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)pThis);

            pThis->m_hwnd = hwnd;
        }
        else
        {
            pThis = (DERIVED_TYPE*)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
        }
        if (pThis)
        {
            //getting read access violation here why?
            //because on resize you are not initializing tiles
            //but resizing the thing
            return pThis->HandleMessage(uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        }
        else
        {
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }

    BaseWindow() : m_hwnd(NULL) { }

    BOOL Create(
        PCWSTR lpWindowName,
        DWORD dwStyle,
        DWORD dwExStyle = 0,
        int x = CW_USEDEFAULT,
        int y = CW_USEDEFAULT,
        int nWidth = CW_USEDEFAULT,
        int nHeight = CW_USEDEFAULT,
        HWND hWndParent = 0,
        HMENU hMenu = 0
    )
    {
        WNDCLASS wc = { 0 };

        wc.lpfnWndProc = DERIVED_TYPE::WindowProc;
        wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
        wc.lpszClassName = ClassName();

        RegisterClass(&wc);

        m_hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
            dwExStyle, ClassName(), lpWindowName, dwStyle, x, y,
            nWidth, nHeight, hWndParent, hMenu, GetModuleHandle(NULL), this
        );

        return (m_hwnd ? TRUE : FALSE);
    }

    //returns handle
    HWND Window() const { return m_hwnd; }

protected:

    virtual PCWSTR  ClassName() const = 0;
    virtual LRESULT HandleMessage(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) = 0;

    HWND m_hwnd;
};
```

`CreateBoard()` method creates the Gems in the board.

```
BOOL MainWindow::CreateBoard()
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < GetcGem(); i++)
    {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < GetcGem(); j++)
        {
            if (Gems[i][j].Create(L"gem", WS_CHILDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, NULL, 
              5 + i * GetsGem().cx + i * 10, 
              5 + j * GetsGem().cy + j * 10, GetsGem().cx, GetsGem().cy, Window(), NULL))
            {
                //pass from main window to Gem object
                Gems[i][j].SetSize(GetsGem().cx, GetsGem().cy);
                Gems[i][j].SetPosition(5 + i * GetsGem().cx + i * 10, 5 + j * GetsGem().cy + j * 10);

                HBRUSH hbrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(125,125,125));
                HBRUSH hOldBrush = (HBRUSH)SetClassLongPtr(Gems[i][j].Window(), GCLP_HBRBACKGROUND, (LONG_PTR)hbrush);
                DeleteObject(hOldBrush);
                InvalidateRect(Gems[i][j].Window(), NULL, TRUE);

            }
            else
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

I want each child window to increase their size by 4 pixels on mouse hover separately. However, after expanding the size, they leave a trace, and sometimes hovering on a single-window increases the size of the whole row or column. Referer to Image, for example:

[image: Problem demo]

I have the handling code for each child window as below. `tracking` is a `static BOOL` in the `GemWindow` class

```
BOOL GemWindow::tracking = false;

LRESULT GemWindow::HandleMessage(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        DestroyWindow(Window());
        break;

    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    {
        if (!tracking) {
            TrackMouse();
            tracking = true;
        }

    }break;

    case WM_MOUSEHOVER:
    {
        MoveWindow(Window(), GetSize().cx + 4, GetSize().cy + 4, GetPosition().x - 2, GetPosition().y - 2, TRUE);
        InvalidateRect(Window(), NULL, TRUE);
        OutputDebugString(L"MOUSE ENTERED\n");
    }break;

    case WM_MOUSELEAVE:
    {
        MoveWindow(Window(), GetSize().cx, GetSize().cy, GetPosition().x, GetPosition().y, TRUE);
        InvalidateRect(Window(), NULL, TRUE);
        OutputDebugString(L"MOUSE LEFT\n");
        tracking = false;
    }break;


    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(m_hwnd, &ps);
        //FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, CreateSolidBrush(color));
        EndPaint(m_hwnd, &ps);
        //OutputDebugString(L"PAINT\n");
    }
    return 0;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(m_hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

`TrackMouse()` is a method of `GemWindow` which initialize a `TRACKMOUSEEVENT`and call `TrackMouseEvent()`

```
    //method for tracking mouse
    void TrackMouse(/*reusability enhanced if you add arguments in the future*/)
    {
        TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme;
        tme.cbSize = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
        tme.dwFlags = TME_HOVER | TME_LEAVE; //Type of events to track & trigger.
        tme.dwHoverTime = 1; //How long the mouse has to be in the window to trigger a hover event.
        tme.hwndTrack = Window();
        TrackMouseEvent(&tme);
    }
```

I thought it is because I am not Updating regions, but doing that did not change anything. I am confused about this bug and can't think of any good reason for it.

Thanks to all who take their time to help.

Comment: How is the window containing your STATICs created?  In particular, please show how the `WNDCLASS` is registered.  Also, off-topic, but calling `DestroyWindow` in response to `WM_DESTROY` is wrong,  `WM_DESTROY` is sent when `DestroyWindow` is called, not the other way round.

Comment: @PaulSanders I used the BaseWindow class given in [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/managing-application-state-) from that inherited my own `GemWindow` class and using the `Create` method on each Gem as `Gems[i][j].Create(L"gem", WS_CHILDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, NULL, 5 + i * GetsGem().cx + i * 10, 5 + j * GetsGem().cy + j * 10, GetsGem().cx, GetsGem().cy, Window(), NULL)` and [the method I use to create the board](https://pastebin.com/z58jF8bF) is here.

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question.  Don't rely on external links.

Comment: @PaulSanders Updated the post according to your suggestion. Didn't want to put everything in the question at first place to keep it as short as possible, I realize whole code for the understandability of the problem should be in the question part but here is a link to  [the project repository](https://github.com/sbecerek/BeJeweled) since a minimal aspect (that seems unrelated to me) of various parts of the code might be causing the problem

Comment: You need to show the code where you register your window class.  That's probably where the problem is.

Comment: @PaulSanders I did update the post but can't seem to relate with it. If you could explain your ideas and your suspicions (if you have an initial idea). I would like to try to focus on those

Comment: It's not that complicated.  I just want to see the code that calls `RegisterClass` (or `RegisterClassEx`).  I don't like shooting in the dark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BOOL MoveWindow(
  HWND hWnd,
  int  X,  //The new position of the left side of the window.
  int  Y,  //The new position of the top of the window.
  int  nWidth, //The new width of the window.
  int  nHeight, //The new height of the window.
  BOOL bRepaint
);
```

Modify the following code:

```
   case WM_MOUSEHOVER:
    {
//      MoveWindow(Window(), GetSize().cx + 4, GetSize().cy + 4, GetPosition().x - 2, GetPosition().y - 2, TRUE);
        MoveWindow(Window(), GetPosition().x - 2, GetPosition().y - 2, GetSize().cx + 4, GetSize().cy + 4, TRUE);            
        ...

    case WM_MOUSELEAVE:
    {
 //     MoveWindow(Window(), GetSize().cx, GetSize().cy, GetPosition().x, GetPosition().y, TRUE);
        MoveWindow(Window(), GetPosition().x, GetPosition().y, GetSize().cx, GetSize().cy,  TRUE);
        ...
```

Debug:

[image]

Comment: so I confused the position argument and the size argument of the  `MoveWindow()` function that is a terrible mistake. Thanks for the answer